# How to force Intellij Idea to redesign/redraw my classes based on new code style?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm using Android studio and I just configured Java code style (`File>Settings>Code Style>Java>Wrapping and Braces`) in a way that displays "{" in new line after class and method definitions.

However, by click on Apply and OK buttons nothing happens although in preview I saw the change.
I restarted the IDE but nothing has changed :(

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only sets the coding style - it does not apply it automatically.

To reformat your code manually, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (or using the menu `Code | Reformat code...`). To reformat the whole source code of your module, just select the module folder first.

More information about reformating source code can be found on the [IntelliJ Web Help](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/reformatting-source-code.html)